# JLabel expanding but not word-wrapping

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, boxlayout

I have a JLabel object for displaying error messages as shown in the following code. As I understand, if the message is embedded within html tags, the label is supposed to word wrap. However, in my case, the label seems to expand horizontally. Can someone please tell me what is it that I am not doing right? Or, is there a better way to display long error messages?

Here's the code:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
  public MyPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    // Several JPanel objects inside

    // The last JPanel to show error messages

    JPanel panelErrMsg = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    this._lblError = new JLabel();
    this._lblError.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 10, 10, 10));
    this._lblError.setForeground(Color.RED);
    this._lblError.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12));
    panelErrMsg.add(this._lblError);
    this.add(panelErrMsg);
  }

  private void DisplayMessage(String msg) {
    String newMessage = "<html><body>" + msg + "</body></html>";
    this._lblError.setText(newMessage);
  }

}
```

Comment: try using a `JTextPane`  with `setEditable(false)` instead?

Comment: A non-editable JTextArea is easier than a JTextPane. That's what I'd recommend. Also, this: "As I understand, if the message is embedded within html tags, the label is supposed to word wrap", is not correct.

Comment: After playing around a little bit, what I noticed is that the panel around the label causes the label not to wrap. If I remove the panel, it does wrap. However, the text starts from the middle of the window and not left. setAlignmentX with LEFT_ALIGNMENT makes no difference.

Comment: Looks like your suggestion of using JTextArea is better. It has word wrap property. As a bonus, you can copy/paste your error messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You may give StyledLabel in the open source JIDE Common Layer a try. It supports line wrapping among many other features that you wish a JLabel could do.

Answer (score 1):

The label needs to have a maximum width for it to wrap.
Try setting the maximum width or wrapping the text in a div tag with a width attribute.

Comment: *"or wrapping the text in a div tag with a width attribute."*  I would usually set a width to the body element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BorderLayout` with `panelErrMsg` and put the label in the NORTH position.